# Find the extreme values of $f(x,y)=xy$ on $D=\{(x,y)|1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This would have to be done using conditional extremes(Lagrange method), and maybe some topological properties.I do not know how to do this, I have only done cases where the $D$ would be defined with one inequality.

Comment: "This would have to be done using conditional extremes(Lagrange method)" - are you saying you're required to do so?

Comment: Note that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb R\left(|xy|\leq \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)$, so you could try to maximize $(x,y)\mapsto \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ on $D$ and try to obtain the equality in the first inequality of this comment. I didn't see it through, don't know if it works, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

The map
$$ \left(x,y\right)\mapsto \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right) $$
is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence your problem is equivalent to finding the extreme values of $\frac{u^2-v^2}{2}$ over $1\leq u^2+v^2\leq 4$. They clearly are $\color{red}{\pm 2}$, and they clearly occur at points of the outer boundary, also because $f(x,y)=xy$ is a [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Maximum_principle) ($\Delta f=0$).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what does $D$ look like? It is a circle with radius $2$ where a circle with radius $1$ is cut out.
In this particular problem, you can first find the maximum of $f(x,y)$ on the circle with radius $1$, which is $D = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$, so you have one inequality, thus you should be able to do so.
Then, you can find the maximum of $f(x,y)$ on the circle with radius $2$, and if this maximum is strictly bigger than the maximum on the first circle, you see that the maximum on $D$ is the latter.

An other way to do this, is switching to polar coordinates.
Then $f(r, \theta) = r^2 \cos( \theta) \sin(\theta)$ with $D = \{ (r ,\theta) \mid 1 \le r^2 \le 4, 0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi \}$.
Then you see that $f(r ,\theta)$ attains it maximum when $r=1$ in case $\cos( \theta) \sin(\theta)$ is always negative, or $r=2$ when $\cos( \theta) \sin(\theta)$ attains positive values.
And in both cases, $\cos( \theta) \sin(\theta)$ can be easily maximized for $\theta$.